# how to INNER JOIN + ALTER TABLE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, alter-table

[Junior Dev here !!!!]

Its seems easy but is not working !

I'm joining 2 tables and i need to change the name of one specify column because i'm multiplying all the values in it.

###### *[Simplified example]*

In one table i have *user_id, date* and in the other one i have *user_id, Q1* (number float)

i need to multiply **Q1*4** to get my **"score"**

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table1.date, table2.Q1*4 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME COLUMN table2.Q1*4 TO score
```

Until ALTER TABLE i m receiving all columns plus the data transformer but with the name table2.Q1*4 when i add ALTER TABLE i m having an error:

Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME COLUMN table2.Q1*4 TO score FROM table1 at line 4

Some questions:

- ALTER TABLE (in case it works) will change my DATABASE or just my answer ?
- Any idea solving my ALTER TABLE error ?
- is good practice to multiply my column in SELECT table2.Q1*4

Thanks

Comment: Ya, this is odd. `ALTER TABLE` changes your database schema. Is that what you really want to do? Or do you actually only need to [change the column name of the output](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/). That's easy: `SELECT table2.Q1*4 score, ...` does it. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Comment: Hi, i just need to change the name for the output and NOT changing the database

Comment: Thanks i will check the alias. And for the multiplication.. Is right to do it in the SELECT line?

Comment: Hi tried out and it work !! Thanks a lot